# Pandas set_index interaction with to_dict and combining columns to show as a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I did df.set_index and listed the names of all the columns I want as keys when I converted into a dictionary.

```
dict = df.set_index(['num1','num2','num3']).to_dict()
```

which outputs a dictionary with the exact keys I want.  However, I want the unnamed columns to be a list of values but it is only showing one column value.

`{('one','two','three') : 8, ('four','seven','three') : 10 ... }`  is the output, however I want it to look like this:

```
{('one','two','three') : [8,6,10], ('four','seven','three'): [10,2,4]
```

How do I get to_dict to output all the columns as a list of values for each key?

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're asking, but it's not clear (to me at least) *why* you want to do this. Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to do with the end result of your question a solution may be more apparent.

Comment: I have an excel sheet.  Various combinations of the first 10 columns will equal one of three values in the last 3 columns.  I translate the excel sheet into a dictionary.  But I am only able to associate one of the values to the keys and would like to have all 3 as a list. The reason why I want to do this is instead of a million if/else statements, I can just search the dictionary using the combinations as keys.  Other code determines which 3 values are chosen.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would go a long way to getting an answer on this, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would be very helpful to get sample data (content of `df` in your question). If you insist on using `to_dict` method I would recommend you the following approach.

1. It's good to always check the documentation of those methods. If you look at [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method documentation, you will find out there is `orient` parameter that is set to "dict" as default but there are other options that might be used.
2. In your case the most suitable solution would be to use `"split"` type that will return dictionary of three keys: **index** (list of indexes), **columns** (list of columns), **data** (list of data).
3. Then you can:

- either use this kind of dictionary

```
df_dict = df.set_index(['num1','num2','num3']).to_dict(orient='split')

idx = df_dict['index'].index(('one','two','three'))
val = df_dict['data'][idx]
# val = [8, 6, 10]
```

- or you can combine this into new dictionary

```
df_dict = df.set_index(['num1','num2','num3']).to_dict(orient='split')
df_dict = dict(zip(a["index"], a["data"]))  # note that I'm renamed your variable to 'df_dict', because 'dict' is builtin method for creation dictionaries
val = df_dict[('one','two','three')]
# val = [8, 6, 10]
```

*Note:
There are of course another ways how to do it, but since you haven't provided any data it's not completely clear if that is what you want. Update your question or comment this answer to make it better.*

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but I was able to eventually come up with this function which has the desired output.  I did not use 'split' but I see a good use for it now.

Comment: {key: [value] + [dict2[key]] for key, value in dict1.items()} was the solution after splitting the data into separate dictionaries